# Tweak the placement and the size of an exponent

Tags: math-mode

How can I place the exponent a little higher and make it a little bigger? As you can see when the exponent is an expression then is seems a little awkward (in my opinion), especially in the document, when it is a lot smaller than in the enlarged picture I provide below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
y= c\cdot e^{\int f_{1}(x)dx}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg I never use `&&` in my documents I just did it in my MWE. I always use the `equation` environment.

Comment: @egreg You are right I didn't think that. I will edit my question. :)

Comment: In a case like this I'd rewrite using `\exp`, much more readable

Answer (score 1):

To get it a little higher you could enclose it in swirly brackets:

```
{e}^{f}
```

And as far as the font size is concerned, play around with this in your preamble (the first parameter must be equal to the class declaration text size):

```
\DeclareMathSizes{}{}{}{}
```